# one2many relation, get parent with child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

```
public void getForm(string scode) {    
Form result = DBContext.Forms.Where(f => f.Code == fCode && f.SCode == sCode).FirstOrDefault();

    result.Products = result.Products.Where(p => p.Deleted== false).ToList(); // commenting this line fix the problem
return result;
}
```

How can we merge above two lines together to avoid below error.

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

**Update:**

When called in another function, it throw above error

```
public void savetrans(string fcode)
{
                    Form form = GetForm(fCode);
                    var transDb = new DbContext.Data.Transaction()
                    {
                        FId = form.FId,
                        field1= "test",
                        field2= "test",
                        field3= "test",
                    };

                    DbContext.Transactions.Add(transactionDb);

                    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove products which are deleted?

Comment: Forms has few products with attached, products has state (deleted, true, false), like to include products, but the ones which have state deleted false. which works fine... But when I try to add transactions for a form it throws above error, by commenting result.products line. that works, so I believe it must be the way it is loaded, if I combine both together somehow using "include" it may fix relationship issue.

Comment: If you want to get Form without deleted product, you can join the tables. If you want to remove the deleted product from database, select them and remove it one by one, then save the data context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete products which are flagged as deleted:

```
var deletedProducts = result.Products.Where(x => x.Deleted).ToList();
foreach(var deletedProduct in deletedProducts)
  result.Products.Remove(deletedProduct);
```

If Form.Products is a `List<Product>` then you can use `.RemoveAll(x => x.Deleted)`

If you just want to exclude deleted products when working with your entity then I'd recommend using an unmapped property for that purpose:

```
public class Form
{
   public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

   [NotMapped]
   public IReadOnlyCollection<Product> ActiveProducts => Products.Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList().AsReadOnly();
   // or
   public IReadOnlyCollection<Product> ActiveProducts
   {
     get { return Products.Where(x => !x.Deleted).ToList().AsReadOnly();
   }
}
```

Then when you want to use only the active products, use `.ActiveProducts`. The caveat of this approach is that you cannot use this property in EF Linq expressions, and it should only be used in a read-only capacity. For instance, don't try something like:

```
var products = context.Forms.Where(x => x.FormId == formId).SelectMany(x => x.ActiveProducts);
```

This will error out because EF wont have ActiveProducts mapped. You'd have to use .Products with the appropriate filter for Deleted.

I'll normally put logic like handling active/inactive when populating view models rather than at the entity level. Entities should reflect the data model, while business logic that applies to how you view/interact with that logic is represented by your view models. The benefit of using a view model is that the inspection of the Active/Deleted state is done once when the view models are populated, and they don't poison the entity with properties that aren't valid in certain uses.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your database has `Forms` and `Products`. There is a one-to-many relation between `Forms` and `Products`: Every `Form` has zero or more `Products`, every `Product` belongs to exactly one `Form` using a foreign key (probably `Product.FormId`)

Your first statement fetches one of your `Forms` that meets certain requirements or null if there is no such `Form`. Without checking the null-return value you try to change the `Products` of this `Form`.

The problem is, that there might be several `Products` that have a  non-nullable foreign key to this `Form`. They are items in the ICollection of `Products` of the Form. If you assigning a new ICollection to `Form.Products`, entity framework wants to set the foreign key of the `Products` that were in `Form.Products` to zero, indicating that this product does not belong to any form anymore. But in your model description you defined that every `Product` should belong to exactly one `Form`. Hence the error.

So what you should do, depends on what you want with your procedure. Do you only want to *Fetch the Form with its non-deleted products*, then you should perform a query. If you want to *remove all deleted products from this forms from the database*, then you should perform an update

#### Query a certain Form with its non-deleted products

```
public ICollection<Form> GetFormWithNonDeletedProducts(string scode)
{
    using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
    {
        return dBContext.Forms                      // from the collection of all Forms
            .Where(form => form.Code == fCode      
                    && form.SCode == sCode)         // keep only the ones that I want
            .Select(form => new Form()              // and create a new Form object
            {                                       // with the properties I plan to use
                 Id = form.Id,
                 Name = form.Name,
                 ...
                 Products = form.Products           // Fetch only the non-deleted products
                     .Where(product => !product.Deleted)
                     .ToList(),
            }
            .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The only reason I need to create a new Product object is because I want to put it in a return value. If you don't need it in a return value, you can put your fetched properties into an anonymous object. This is usually more efficient, because you won't fetch data you won't used from the database.

For example the above example will assign `Product.FormId`. You won't need it, becasue you know that all thousand Products of this Form will have the same value FormId: namely the value of `Form.Id`.

The same query without fetching properties you don't use (anonymous types)

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    return dBContext.Forms                  // from the collection of all Forms
        .Where(form => form.Code == fCode      
            && form.SCode == sCode)         // keep only the ones that I want
        .Select(form => new                 // and create a new Form object
        {                                   // with the properties I plan to use
                 Id = form.Id,
                 Name = form.Name,
                 ...
                 Products = form.Products   // Fetch only the non-deleted products
                     .Where(product => !product.Deleted)
                     .Select(product => new
                      {                     // Select only properties you plan to use
                          Name = product.Name,
                          Price = product.Price,

                          // not meaningful: you already know the value:
                          // FormId = product.FormId,
                      })
                     .ToList(),
        }
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

#### Update the database: remove the deleted products of the form

Although your function is called `GetForms` it seems you want to use it to remove the deleted products.

The easiest way is to use `DbSet<Products>.RemoveRange`:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(...))
{
    // remove all Deleted products of the form with Code equal to fCode
    // and SCode equal to sCode
    var productsToDelete = dbContext.Products
        .Where(product => product.Deleted
            && product.Form.Code == fCode
            && product.Form.Scode == sCode);
    // note: query is not executed yet!

    dbContext.Products.RemoveRange(productsToDelete);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

It might be that you'll have to do `RemoveRange(productsToDelete.ToList())`, you'll have to check this.